# Printing to imz320 with zpl content containing Arabic text from ios using cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, platform, zpl

I am developing a hybrid application using cordova. I am able to print zpl content with arabic texts in android version. But the same zpl code is not working in ios version. The printer gets the signal and the blue light blinks. but not getting printed, when the content has an arabic text.

I am using Zebra iMZ320 printer. Can you please share a working example for the same, with arabic contents for ios.

```js
var TestPrint = "^XA^FO50,50^A@E:TT0003M_.TTF,N,50,50^FD"+"الفئة الرابعة عشر"+"^FS ^XZ";
//-- "ÙØ­Ø§ÙÙØ©"
localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name = 'XXXXJ142401535';
window.plugins.CordovaPrinter.print(
    function (success) { // Call the print method
        console.log('Platform : ios, Successfully printed...'
                   + '\n thru. ',localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name);
        },
    function error(err) {
        console.log('Error Printing to ' + localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name);
        console.log(err);
    },
    localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name, //serialArray[0],
    TestPrint);
```

Comment: Adding the code that you tried will help people to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - Purus, I have shared the code now

Comment: do you get any error log in the console?

Comment: No. The printer led just blinks and goes off. But not getting printed

Answer (score 0):

after struggling for more than a month, finally found a solution for the issue to be as follows:

```js
//-ARABIC TEXT ENCODING - FOR IOS---------------------------
/*-----String to utf-8 encoded hex-----*/
function toHex(str,hex){
  try{
    //We have appended '-', because, you need to prefix the utf-8 hex code with an underscore, to be printed in ZPL
    hex = '_' + unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
    .split('').map(function(v){
      return v.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    }).join('_')
  }
  catch(e){
    hex = str
    console.log('invalid text input: ' + str)
  }
  return hex
}
//-EXAMPLE : console.log('toHex of ' + str + ' is : ' + toHex(str, 16));

//----------------------------------------------------------
var TestPrint = "^XA" +
"^LH100,150" +
"^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT" +
"^CFT,30,30" +
"^CI28" +
"^FT0,0^FH^FDTesting 1 2 3...^FS" + 
"^FT0,50^FH^FD" +toHex(str, 16)+ "^FS" +
"^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS" +
"^XZ" ;
console.log('TestPrint : ', TestPrint);

localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name = 'XXXXJ142401535';
window.plugins.CordovaPrinter.print(
    function (success) { // Call the print method
        console.log('Platform : ios, Successfully printed...'
                   + '\n thru.', localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name);
        },
    function error(err) {
        console.log('Error Printing to ' + localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name);
        console.log(err);
    },
    localStorage.iosConnected_ZebraPrinter_Name, //serialArray[0],
    TestPrint);
```

Comment: @SSubhaharan can we convert html into ZPL?